# Standard way to handle a series of lists of custom classes

Tags: c#, list, win-universal-app

Sorry about the vague title. My problem is as follows:

I have a series of classes (classA, classB, classC...) and I have a list for each class. I want to be able to let the user Import, Export, Add, and Remove on these lists.

The way I attempted to handle this problem is:

- Create a public, static class to work as a global class.
- For each class create a list ( public static List aList = new List();  ) inside the global class.
- Use JSON to save & load the lists between instances (and also for import/export in the future)
- Use reflection and generate a FieldInfo for each list.
- Send the FieldInfo for classA to the deleteObjectFromList page
- Try to use Interfaces to create a list and cast list to list

I obviously can't cast list to list because I am not allowed to add objects of classB to a list of classA, even though they are both implementing the interface.

I have considered creating a custom listClass and try to handle the casting in that way, but it seems messy.

What is the best way to handle this problem? I don't want to have to handle each class individually because there will realistically be +20 classes.

Since code snippets were requested, here is my global class.

```
public static class globalClass
{
    public static List<classA> characterList = new List<classA>();
    public static List<classB> raceList = new List<classB>();
    public static List<classC> deityList = new List<classC>();
}
```

One of my custom classes used for a list,

```
public class classA: IInterface
{
    public string getDisplayName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    //general info
    public String name;
}
```

How I am saving a list

```
private async Task saveItem<T>(List<T> list, string p)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(list.GetType());

        //changed "LocalFolder" to "RoamingFolder"
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                            p,
                            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, list);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("done writing!");
    }
```

How I am getting the FieldInfo and passing it to the next page on my App.

```
TypeInfo typeInfo = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(globalClass));
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> FieldInfoList = typeInfo.DeclaredFields;

foreach (FieldInfo f in FieldInfoList)
{
   Button deleteButton = new Button();
   deleteButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
          Frame.Navigate(typeof(deleteObjectFromLibraryPage), f);
       };
}
```

and how I was trying to get the actual list from the fieldinfo I sent.

```
private List<IDisplayable> list;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        FieldInfo f = (FieldInfo)e.Parameter;
        String s = f.GetValue(null).ToString();

        TypeInfo typeInfo = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(globalClass));
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> FieldInfoList = typeInfo.DeclaredFields;

        var v = FieldInfoList.Where(c => c.GetType().Equals(f.GetType()));
        this.list = globalClass.getList(f);
    }
```

The last line of the above code is where I became stuck, and wanted to figure out the standard approach to this problem.

Comment: Your approach seems pretty bad IMO. It's too cumbersome, and you're resorting to reflection. Use proper generics instead. BTW, post relevant code if you don't want to get your question cloed.

Comment: @HighCore Yes, my approach is my problem, that is what I want help with. I've added my relevant code.

Comment: See solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279923/generate-button-for-each-list/25280341#25280341

Comment: @CarlHembrough Yes, that is also my question. I suppose it's useful to have the answer here for others sake.