# generate button for each list

Tags: c#, list

I have a series of lists in a static class (used as a global class)

```
public static class globalClass
{
    public static List<classA> aList = new List<classA>();
    public static List<classB> bList = new List<classB>();
    public static List<classC> cList = new List<classC>();
}
```

I want to generate a xaml button for each list, and was told reflection was a bad idea. This is how I handled it using reflection.

```
//get FieldInfo for globalClass
TypeInfo typeInfo = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(globalClass));
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> FieldInfoList = typeInfo.DeclaredFields;

foreach (FieldInfo f in FieldInfoList)
{
    //Only look at lists
    if(f.FieldType.ToString().StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.List`1")){
        StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
        s.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.FontSize = 45;
        textBlock.Text = f.Name.ToString();

        Button addButton = new Button();
        addButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(addObjectToLibraryPage), f);
        };
        addButton.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        addButton.Name = "addButton";
        addButton.Content = "add";

        Button deleteButton = new Button();
        deleteButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(deleteObjectFromLibraryPage), f);
        };
        deleteButton.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        deleteButton.Name = "deleteButton";
        deleteButton.Content = "delete";

        s.Children.Add(addButton);
        s.Children.Add(deleteButton);

        //add new textBlock and stackpanel to existing xaml
        stackPanel.Items.Add(textBlock);
        stackPanel.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this? Hopefully I would like to be able to pass the actual list instead of a FieldInfo.

I don't want to have to handle each list individually because I may end up with 20+ lists and am using them all in a very similar way.

An example of what I am trying to do:

Suppose I have a grocery/nutrition App, and I want users to be able to record what they eat/need from the store. They can select from a list of Fruit, Vegetables, Meat, Dairy, Sweets, Canned Goods, Etc..

But, I want them to be able to (as an advanced option) be able to edit the list of possible fruits, or any other food category. And I don't want to just have a list of "food" because meat will record things like minimum cooking temperature or something like that.

So, under advanced options, I would want two buttons for each category (add to fruit, delete from fruit). And theoretically add an Import/Export page so I can share my list of fruits with other people or something.

It doesn't seem like the answers pointing to using a superclass will work. See: [C# polymorphism simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231668/c-sharp-polymorphism-simple-question)

Comment: Why are you creating 20 static lists? What is the purpose of this construction?

Comment: Where does reflection come into this? if its a static class then there can't be that much there to reflect.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I want to be able to make groups of custom classes that can be edited. (a list of fruit, vegetables, dairy, etc..) They are static so they can be treated as 'global' and they are lists because I want to be able to add and remove elements.

Comment: @Sayse I want to be able to perform actions "for each" list, the only way I figured out how to do that was reflection.

Comment: I personally think your whole approach is wrong, chances are you have alot of list items which means you are overloading the user with way too many buttons to comprehend. I'm not sure of the need for a static class here  but that could be due to lack of context. In short, the main problems with reflection (again, opinion) is that it exposes a problem with program flow and it is slower than the alternatives. The speed may not be too much of an issue if this action is only performed once

Comment: @Sayse What are the alternatives? I posted an example to give a better idea what I am trying to do.

Comment: Alternative one is to store all food in a database (removes static class) and then include a field to show whether to display this food or not. Alternative two is to have an object model with inheritance (base class food which has a display boolean) where each different type of object can have its own values/requirements. Note: I have little experience with database design but I would imagine that these two approaches can even be combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list to contain all the existing lists you have. You can then iterate over the list to create the buttons. If you wish to maintain a label for each list you could use a dictionary with the key as the label text and list as the value.

The proposed solution aside, do take into account the comments given from Sayse.

Comment: I tried List<List> but it needs a type for the inner list, and I can't do List<List<class>> because each list is a different class. Could you post an example of how to do that?

Comment: Have a base class for all objects that would go into the list if you haven't already got one. Then create List<List<BaseObject>>. That is assuming that you can do all that you need to do on the front end polymorphically.

Comment: I can't add an element of type subClass to a list of type baseClass?

Comment: Yes you can. Ensure your subclass inherits from the baseclass and that the list is declared as List<baseclass>. When creating a list of lists be sure to instantiate each inner list that gets added to the outer list.

Comment: I am getting cast errors, and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2231868/3135602) seems to show it's not possible. Maybe another example would be helpful because I am not seeing how this could work.

Comment: I will need to know exactly what you are doing with the lists to determine where there is an issue. The solution given assumes that you can satisfy your requirements by using each class as if it were its base type (polymorphism). What need do you have to cast? Where is your cast exception occurring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59255/discussion-between-tain-and-carlhembrough).